# Is this an example of an SQL Injection Attack?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, sql-injection

I developed a web site for a client where they will post images of their merchandise online.  The url is `www.domiainname.com/item-details.cfm?sku=125`.  Someone tried browsing to `www.domiainname.com/item-details.cfm?sku=125%20and%203=3` which produced and error in which I'm notified.

I've also received error reports of:

```
item-details.cfm?sku=1291+or+1=@@version-- 
item-details.cfm?sku=1291'+or+1=@@version 
item-details.cfm?sku=1291+or+1=@@version
```

The last three examples are definitely of someone trying to get into the system, right?

If we converted this to be stored procedures, would that reduce or eliminate the risk of insertion attacks?

Comment: And yes, the queries are wrapped in cfqueryparam tags (e.g. `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#sku_id#">`

Comment: I understand what they were trying to do with the @@version but what on earth would 3=3 tell them?  My error catcher also reports the IP address.  I've thought about adding a db table and added IP's that I receive from situations like that and then rereouting those users to google or something.  Is this effective or that just an exercise in futililty?

Comment: By adding a tautology (e.g., 3=3) they are trying to get all the results from the database they can. However, perhaps they're not as smart as all that because they would need to use OR in that case instead of AND! As long as you're using `<cfqueryparam>` you should be safe from SQL injection attacks (at least on SELECTs, you might still be vulnerable to XSS attacks on INSERTs and UPDATEs). Still, it is a good idea to validate your parameters so you can trap the error before it happens -- try doing `<cfset sku_id = val(url.sku) />` to trap this one, or use `isNumeric()` to be notified.

Comment: seems like they probably meant to use `OR 3=3` hoping it would return all values from the database

Comment: Just adding a good resource I ran across today: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/sql_injection.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it appears that someone is being malicious.

Using [`cfqueryparam`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_18.html) will prevent SQL-injection attacks. When in doubt (and it's CF), ask Ben:

[SQL Injection Attacks, Easy To Prevent, But Apparently Still Ignored](http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2005/12/21/SQL-Injection-Attacks-Easy-To-Prevent-But-Apparently-Still-Ignored)

Example:

```
<cfquery ...>
    SELECT    *
    FROM      Products
    WHERE     SKU=<cfqueryparam value="#URL.SKU#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Marking this as correct as it is the most thorough answer (e.g. example usage, links to Ben's blog, and livedocs).  The other two answers are technically correct as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use [cfqueryparam](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_18.html) and forget about any sql-injection ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, someone attempted SQL injection. If you check the `sku` variable correctly in your code, this will not do any harm.