# Flex Coldfusion variable cross population

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, flex4.6

I'm connecting a Flex 4.6 form to SQL Server 2008 using Coldfusion. When my form submits to the DB, I'm finding my variables are crossing and I can't seem to see the problem causing it:

**Flex Remote Object Call:**

```
private function RegisterNewEmployee():void{
    //remote object and method instantiated 
    roCreateNewUser.createNewEmployeeProfile(fm_userName.text, 
    fm_password.text, fm_accessLevel.selectedItem, fm_emailAddress.text, 
    fm_domainField.selectedItem ); 
}
```

**Flex Components**

```
<mx:FormItem label="Access Level:" width="182" color="#FFFFFF" required="false">
    <s:DropDownList width="60" color="#FFFFFF" id="fm_accessLevel">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <mx:ArrayList id="accessLevelList">
                <fx:String>9</fx:String>
                <fx:String>44</fx:String>
            </mx:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:DropDownList>
</mx:FormItem>
<mx:FormItem label="Email: " fontSize="12" width="173" horizontalAlign="left" color="#FFFFFF" required="false"><s:TextInput color="#000000" id="fm_emailAddress" text="{fm_userName.text}" />
</mx:FormItem><s:Label text="@&#xd;&#xd;&#xd;" fontSize="14" width="15" height="21" color="#FEFEFE" />
<s:ComboBox color="#FFFFFF" id="fm_domainField" height="22" enabled="true">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <mx:ArrayList id="domainList">
            <fx:String>aaa.com</fx:String>
            <fx:String>bbb.com</fx:String>
            <fx:String>ccc.com</fx:String>
        </mx:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:ComboBox>
```

**Coldfusion Code:**

```
<cfargument name="fm_accessLevel" type="any" default="1"> 
<cfargument name="fm_emailAddress" type="any" default="user01"> 
<cfargument name="fm_domainField" type="any" default="aaa.com">
```

**Problem begins here:**

```
<!--- Concatenate email and domain --->
<cfset emailString = #arguments.fm_emailAddress# & "@" & #arguments.fm_domainField# >
```

Somehow, the outcome of the concatenation returns the equivalent of

```
<cfset emailString = #arguments.accessLevel# & "@" & #arguments.emailAddress# >
or **44@MyUserName** in plain text output
```

Any noticeable issues in the code to cause this? It previously worked without 
   issue. Cache and browser history cleared, issue persists.

Comment: *It previously worked without issue* What has changed?  Does it happen every time, or only sometimes?  If it is sporadic, is the `emailString` variable VAR/LOCAL scoped inside the function? If not, could be typical race conditions. LOCAL scoping that variable, and any other function local variables, will fix it.

Comment: Code wise, nothing has changed. what is happening is sometimes it renders accessLevel value @ userName othertimes it did userName @ accessLevel value. Its even somehow cast  a variable argument.position @ accessLevel. Its just behaving very unsual.

Comment: (Edit) Well, like I said above, if it is sporadic it might be a possible race condition. Is the variable localized or not? Also, have you logged the values at each point in the process to pinpoint where in the process things break? If the function is not receiving the correct values, that points to a Flex problem. If the function *does* receive the correct values, but only the concatenation is wrong, it points to a problem within the function code.

Comment: The variable is localized to the function. When I've tested my function using a .cfm page to dump the variables and complete the concatenation, it did so without an issue. When it was passed from flex to CF, the values were correct. However, once the values made it into the DB table, that is where I saw the variables somehow were wrong and not doing as the code above reads .

Comment: With sporadic errors, you need to keep logging until the error occurs again, to know exactly where things break.  If ALL of your function variables are properly localized, it sounds like it should work, but ... obviously something is different than you are assuming. Adding detailed logging at each step will pinpoint where in the application things are going wrong ie Flex, CF or SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this an example of an SQL Injection Attack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668075/is-this-an-example-of-an-sql-injection-attack)